# cost a huge time because the number is huge?

Tags: java

I have a program which involves with a bunch of huge numbers (I have to put them into bignumbers type). The time complexity is unexpectedly huhge too. So, I was wondering, do these two factors have a connections? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: how large are the numbers? what are you trying to compute?

Comment: Based on the information you provided us we can't help you. If you want help post your code and a running example (input), how long does it run etc.

Comment: *Technically* addition is O(log n) where n is the max/min number. You'll see this more with software implementations like `BigInteger`, but log(2^128) is still only 128. Like @saadtaame said, just how big are these numbers?

Comment: Time complexity of *what?* And if you really already know the time complexity, you already know the answer. Do you mean 'performance' as measured in elapsed time?

Answer (score 1):

Do they have a *connection to each other?* Probably not.

You can have a large complexity algorithm working on small numbers (such as calculating the set of all sets for ten thousand numbers all in the range `0..30000`) and you can have very efficient algorithms working on large numbers (such as simply adding up ten thousand `BigInteger` variables).

However, they'll both probably have a cascading effect on the time it takes your program to run. Large numbers will add a bit, a high-complexity algorithm will add a bit more I say 'add' but the effect is likely to be multiplicative, much worse - for example, using an inefficient algorithm may may your code take 30% longer, and the use of `BigInteger` may add 30% to *that,* giving you a 69% overall hit:

```
t * 1.3 * 1.3 = 1.69t
```

Sorry for the general answer but, without more specifics in the question, a general answer is the best you'll probably get. In any case, I believe (or at least hope) it answers the question you asked.